# Reading only two out of three columns with read.csv

Tags: r

I have an ascii dataset which consists of three columns, but only the last two are actual data. Now I want to create a dotchart of the data by using `read.csv(file = "result1", sep= " ")`. R reads all three columns. How do I avoid this?

Comment: I'll leave it here, but please ask future basic R questions on [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Actually, the current consensus seems to be that R questions are now welcome in CV. I can't find the discussion right now, but it's somewhere in http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788117/only-read-limited-number-of-columns-in-r

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `colClasses` argument to `read.csv` to select the columns you want.  In this case, you can set `colClasses` to `c("NULL", NA, NA)`

```
read.csv(file="result1", sep=" ", colClasses=c("NULL", NA, NA))
```

More generally, you can use colClasses to specify the particular types of columns; `NA` means to use the default approach which is to try and figure out what the column is automatically.  See the help page for `read.csv` for more details.

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to read in the whole file, but keep only two of the columns, e.g.:

```
read.csv(file = "result1", sep = " ")[ ,1:2]
```

or, using column names, eg. if columns are named 'col1, col2, col3'

```
read.csv(file = "result1", sep = " ")[ ,c('col1', 'col2')]
```

Comment: Answer by @Brian takes less time as compared to yours.

Answer (score 0):

This one takes less time as compared to the provided answers

```
library(data.table)
fread(file="result1", sep=" ", colClasses=c("NULL", NA, NA))
```